# How to change column data type without loosing data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, alter-table, alter

I have a city_id column which has **varchar(255) and null values**.I want to change it to **big integer**.

I will use:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
ALTER COLUMN CITY_ID BIGINT
```

Do I loose or corrupt any data ?

Comment: What values are in the column?  Obviously, if there are values that cannot be represented as a big integer, you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a new big integer column as an intermediate step:

```
-- add new column
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD COLUMN CITY_ID_NEW BIGINT;

-- populate new column
UPDATE Customer
SET CITY_ID_NEW = CAST(CITY_ID AS UNSIGNED);

-- drop old column and rename new column
ALTER TABLE Customer DROP COLUMN CITY_ID;
ALTER TABLE Customer CHANGE COLUMN CITY_ID_NEW CITY_ID BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

I assume above that your integer values are all positive, i.e. they are not signed.  If you want signed integers, then change the cast in the update to `SIGNED`.